# I'm a bit lost on DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Alright. As a part of a personal project to get familiar with Javascript, css and html outside of tutorials I've decided to try to create a cookie clicker like game for fun. However, I'm a bit stuck on the DOM manipulation.

```
var multiplier=1;
var money=5;
var moneyTotal=money*multiplier;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div #button').click(function() {
        var money++;
    });
});

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = moneyTotal;
```

What I'm trying to do is having some text in my html index page, that changes whenever you click the div with the ID button. That piece of text has the id counter. But I can't seem to make this work, and I'm starting to get really frustrated after having this problem for 4 hours and not finding a solution. I have a feeling I'm missing some very obvious syntax, but I have no idea on what.

Edit:
Alright I changed the code so that it looks like this now:

```
var multiplier=1;
var money=5;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        money++;
        $('#counter').html(money * multiplier);
    });
});
```

However it still won't target my div with the ID counter.
Here's the index.html, but I'm 99% sure there's no syntax errors there, and I have no idea on why it won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button"></div>
    <div id="counter">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
This is the final solution, thanks again everyone!

```
var mp = 1
var money = 0

$(document).ready(function() {
    var localMoney = localStorage.getItem("money");
    var localmp = localStorage.getItem("mp")
    $('#moneycounter').click(function() {
        money++;
        $('#counter').html(money * mp);
});
});
```

Comment: var money + 1 should be either money += 1 or money ++, also as you're using Jquery anyway you can use it to insert your total: $('#counter').html(moneyTotal) [which should also be in the same click event function];

Comment: If you want to change the content of an element when the button is clicked, you have to move that logic *inside* the click event handler. I recommend to go through the jQuery tutorial, which should get you started properly: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/, http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Comment: I updated the main post a bit, and I did go through a jQuery course. Still can't manage to make it target the div with the counter ID.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wyEM6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do...

But `var money +1` is wrong. Should be `money++`

Then you have to recalculate `moneyTotal`, and set it into the `innerHTML` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the function to update your div everytime you click!

```
var multiplier=1;
var money=5;
var moneyTotal=money*multiplier;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div #button').click(function() {
        money++;
        updateElement();
    });
});


function updateElement(){
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = moneyTotal;
}
```